# numpy set_printoptions format for whole dollars

Tags: python, numpy

I want the output of revenue and expenses to be in whole dollars. I have set the print options to int however I still receive the decimal point and cannot see in the docs how I would display the whole amount as dollars.

```
revenue = [14574.49, 7606.46, 8611.41, 9175.41, 8058.65, 8105.44, 11496.28, 9766.09, 10305.32, 14379.96, 10713.97, 15433.50]
expenses = [12051.82, 5695.07, 12319.20, 12089.72, 8658.57, 840.20, 3285.73, 5821.12, 6976.93, 16618.61, 10054.37, 3803.96]
```

Here is my code which works but I cannot format to whole dollars.

```
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(precision=0, formatter={'int_kind':':d'})
revenue_arr = np.array(revenue)
expense_arr = np.array(expense)

profits = revenue_arr - expense_arr
print(profits)
```

**Result**

```
[ 10771.   3802.   4807.   5371.   4255.   4301.   7692.   5962.   6501.
  10576.   6910.  11630.]
```

**Desired Result**

```
[ $10771   $3802   $4807   $5371   $4255   $4301   $7692   $5962   $6501
      $10576   $6910  $11630]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profits is actually a float array.
You can set numpy to print the dollar sign by

```
 np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: '${:.0f}'.format(x)})
```

outputs:

```
 >>> print(profits)
 [$2523 $1911 $-3708 $-2914 $-600 $7265 $8211 $3945 $3328 $-2239 $660 $11630]
```

**Edit:**

To have the minus on the left of the dollar sign on negative values, a slightly more complex formatting is needed, for example:

```
def dollar_formatter(x):
     if x >= 0:
         return '${:.0f}'.format(x)
     else:
         return '-${:.0f}'.format(-x)

np.set_printoptions(precision=0, formatter={'float': dollar_formatter})
```